# Printf executes twice in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

Very simple program as an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int c; // has to be int so it's large enough to hold EOF
        printf("Please press EOF (C^D in Linux)\n");
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                printf("That's not EOF! Try again.\n"); // why is this printed twice?
        printf("EOF is ");
        putchar(c);
        printf(".\n");
}
```

The question is simple as well: why is line 8 executed twice? Shouldn't it work like this:

1. Get input from the user and assign the value to variable `c`.
2. Check if `c` isn't `EOF`.
3. If it isn't, print *That's not EOF! Try again.* Go to step 1.
4. If it is, print *EOF is [whatever EOF is].*.
5. Terminate the program.

Instead of that, the step 3 is:

3. If it isn't, print *That's not EOF! Try again.* twice. Go to step 1.

Confusing problem. Will someone explain to me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: simply as enter is a character input...

Comment: How many keys did you press, one or two?